# Best way to make JSON out of PHP and display it in my jQuery success case?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have this code in jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
  $("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    var name = $("#problem_name").val();
    var problem_blurb = $("#problem_blurb").val();

    var dataString = 'problem_name='+ name + '&problem_blurb=' + problem_blurb;

    if(name=='' || problem_blurb == '') {
      $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
      $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
    }
    else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/problems/add_problem.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
          $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
          $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();

          // Here can update the right side of the screen with the newly entered information
          alert (dataString);
        }
      });
    }

    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

And I have an AJAX call that I want to make JSON so I can unpack the JSON in the success case of the call to the AJAX.

What I don't understand is how to create the JSON and how to make the front end detect it, and how to unpack it and display it.  Any advice with that?

My backend return will be simple. Just a name and description for every item returned.

Comment: So you want your PHP backend to return a JSON string, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of what you want to return in php, preferably an associative array but it could be integer indexed and it will work just as well.

```
$arr = array();
// Fill array with return data with PHP.
$arr['name'] = 'John';

echo json_encode($arr);
```

That will render your array as output in JSON format, which your jQuery success function will pick up in a **parameter**.  Below, I name the parameter `json` but you can name it whatever you like.

```
...
success: function(json) {
   var ob = $.parseJSON(json);
   // At this point, ob is a JavaScript object that should look pretty much the same 
   // as the PHP object you created.
   alert(ob.name); // In this example, will alert 'John'
}
...
```

Also note that `$.parseJSON` was not introduced in jQuery until version 1.4.1.

Please see: [PHP Manual: json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Thanks..1 question - how do I send the encoded json from the php to be in the json variable of the "success: function(json)"  ?

Comment: That's the magic of jQuery's AJAX.  Any output from your back end PHP script will appear as a string parameter passed to your success function.  Since you are outputting JSON, I named the variable 'json'.

Comment: by output do you mean I have to do something like echo $json; ....or whats the way to output the $json once its encoded?

Comment: The function `json_encode` will take an array and return a string containing that array in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON).  The last line of my first code block takes that string and simply echos it out (making it _output_)

Answer (score 5):

In `add_problem.php` use PHP's `json_encode()` on the object/array/scalar you want to return.

In your javascript, use jQuery's `.getJSON()` to make your AJAX call. Alternatively, you can use jQuery's `.ajax()` function and specify `dataType: 'json'`.

Here's documentation on jQuery's `.getJSON()`:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

and here's some documentation on the PHP `json_encode()` function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Adding a header is a good idea too: header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: @Jonathan In my php I have a result set variable I get from the database. Should I encode that? Or make it into an object first?

Comment: @Genadinik, definitely make the result set an object first, or else you get all the extra methods that go with the result set. Just make an object that contains the data only.

Comment: @BradKoch, technically, yes, that's a good idea, but jQuery seems to handle it just fine without the header. Here's a good discussion on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type

Comment: @Genadinik, it goes in the PHP code.  Jonathan, Excellent link. I know it's not necessary, but it's just proper to send a correct MIME type.